# can we push .so files inside android so no need to integrate with application

Tags: android, android-studio

I have integrated .so libraries files with my apk source but it is crashing so is there any way like I will push all library inside android folder and application will take library from there.

I have fixed cpu architecture(arm cortex a34) so no need to built **different** so files.

Answer (score 0):

*.so library in Android Studio

You have to generate jniLibs folder inside main in android Studio projects and put your all .so files inside. You can also integrate this line in build.gradle

compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['.jar','.so'])

It's work perfectly

|--app:

|--|--src:

|--|--|--main

|--|--|--|--jniLibs

|--|--|--|--|--armeabi

|--|--|--|--|--|--.so Files

This is the project structure.

Comment: This works if the .so files have nothing to do with hardware, i.e. USB and are for the architecture of the particular smartphone

Comment: i have already done it but  i dont want this. i want to push all files in android. i do not want to integrate with android

Comment: @ralfhtp i am using arm mali cpu for particular use so i do not have to care about hardware my .so files already built for the same hardware